# rails 3.2.6 application wont start - wrap_parameters.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby version - 
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

rails version - 
Rails 3.2.6

gem version - 1.8.15

os - ubuntu 12.04

I did run `sudo gem install rubygems-update -v 1.8.24` to update the rubygems version

after I start the rails server, I get an exception

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/work/AptanaWorkspace/ordernile/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
                         ^
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: those paths imply you're running ruby 1.8, not 1.9.3

Comment: The error about using the JavaScript-style Hash syntax also indicates that you're using Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

The question description is not enough to say what could cause exceptions. But it's obvious that Ruby on Rails was running under ruby 1.8 NOT 1.9.

My suggestion is:

- Install one of the following ruby version management tool. [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/). They will help you to manage ruby version across the system, switching Ruby version between different projects. I personally prefer rbenv, the site lists all the advantages.

After installing and configuring your project or global Ruby version:
1. Double check your current ruby version by `ruby --version`
2. run `gem install bundler`
3. under project root folder run `bundle update`

If RoR's Gemfile is configured correctly, the second step should be able to install all the dependencies. Make sure you have database configuration all setup as well as completed the `rake db:migrate`

Comment: That's not a concise answer :)

Comment: I'm just a big rvm fan -- can't help it!

Comment: we use both RVM and rbenv on several dev/test/production/systems. no obvious differences, just it seems that rbenv has much cleaner solution for production environment. Both works great I would say. RVM has awesome cartoon home page :o)